# Flutter keyboard disappears when streambuilder rebuilds

Tags: flutter, virtual-keyboard

I have a textformfield inside a streambuilder, since I need to show it only if Firestore documents match some criterias.

The problem is that when there is new data in the database, the streambuilder rebuilds (and that's fine) and if I had the virtual keyboard open, it closes.

Is there any way to prevent the keyboard from closing?

edit: I add some code

```
     StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bets').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot msgSnapshot) {
            if (msgSnapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error');
            }

            if (msgSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            }

            if (msgSnapshot.hasData) {
              

              _focusNode.requestFocus();                  

              return Container( ....
```

this is the streambuilder code, so the requestfocus should fire at each new data arrival. But it doesn't.

This is the textformfield:

```
Container(
          width: 200,
          child: TextFormField(
            //autofocus: true,
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            controller: myController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Inserisci',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Colors.grey.shade800,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The only workaround (sort of) I found is setting autofocus to true, but that's not a real option because anyway the keyboard disappears for a second before popping up again, so it's not ideal in case of the user is typing.

why the set focus doesn't work inside of my streambuilder?

Answer (score -1):

on a particular condition of stream builder assign focusnode to that textfield

Comment: thanks, I updated my question with some code. Your solution would be nice, but it does not work for me..

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could provide an example.